# papaparse csv to json nested array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, csv, papaparse

I have a CSV file which has `image[0].url,image[1].url` like headers. I want it to be a nested element as below. By parsing the CSV to JSON with papaparse, is there anyway i can do that?

```
"image": [
  {
    "url": "https://invimg2.autofunds.net/InventoryImages/2021/11/24/3870_1699274_DC1_11288561_738124382021.jpg",
    "tag": [
      "Used 2011 BMW 3 Series 328i xDrive Sedan 4D"
    ]
  },
  {
    "url": "https://invimg2.autofunds.net/InventoryImages/2021/11/24/3870_1699274_DC2_83755912_738324382021.jpg"
  },
  {
    "url": "https://invimg2.autofunds.net/InventoryImages/2021/11/24/3870_1699274_DC3_47085920_738324382021.jpg"
  },
  {
    "url": "https://invimg2.autofunds.net/InventoryImages/2021/11/24/3870_1699274_DC4_16905684_738324382021.jpg"
  },
  {
    "url": "https://invimg2.autofunds.net/InventoryImages/2021/11/24/3870_1699274_DC5_10751374_738324382021.jpg"
  }
],
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.